# Where to find the Java 9 module descriptor reference?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

It seems that the [latest state of the module system](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules) is a bit outdated as it still mentions 'requires public' instead of 'requires transitive'.

Where can I find the latest spec on the module system?

Comment: Questions for documentation are out of scope for SO. That said, I think there is none. Mark Reinhold recently mentioned that he wants to update the _State of the Module System_, so I assume we just have to wait.

Comment: @Nicolai, thanks. BTW - great talk on voxxed.

Comment: @Nicolai, I think you are being too harsh. It did not attract opinionated response nor spam. Mark answered himself and this was very helpful for me. The fact that it may be irrelevant over time is not mentioned in the rules.

Comment: The rule does not say to close such questions _if_ they attract opinionated response or spam but _if_ they ask for off-site resources (because that _might_ attract opinionated response or spam). Still, maybe you are right and I was to quick to close. You got a good answer, though, so nothing bad came from closing. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*The State of the Module System*](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms) is indeed out of date; I hope to update it soon.  In the meantime the current working-draft specification can always be found [here](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~mr/jigsaw/spec/).